# How to have the desired output using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello everyone I am new to Selenium and I am having some trouble to find the output that I want.
I wrote the following code in order to have the title of the first article of the skynews website :

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://news.sky.com/')


title = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sdc-site-tile__headline')

print(title)
```

The output of this should be : "PM says Royal Navy to stay on patrol in jersey as French military ships head to fishing protest".
and this is what I want to have.
however I have instead :

```py
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="05a161b52d544d45f8b12b6eab64ee6e", element="a5e7b959-ea4f-4bba-a52d-f6d327642399")>
```

anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple issues....first you are printing the element directly, that won't give you the output you desire (as you saw above).  You need to print the `text` value within that element.  Second issue is that locator you specified has 207 instances on that webpage, so you need to narrow it down to the one you want.

To get the text from that exact article specified you can use this XPath:

```
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='sdc-site-tile__headline-text'])[2]")

print(title.text)
```

**Updated full code** --added piece to handle cookie-accept popup message when first entering site

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://news.sky.com/')

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='sp_message_iframe_479654']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Accept']").click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()

title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='sdc-site-tile__headline-text'])[2]")

print(title.text)
```

Prints...

```
PM says Royal Navy to stay on patrol in Jersey as French fishing boats leave after Brexit protest
```

Comment: when I run your code it gaves me an "invalid syntax" error ..

Comment: hmmm, not sure why.  It works fine for me.  I did edit it after I originally answered, my parentheses were in the wrong place

Comment: i just updated reply to show the full code

Comment: yep now it works, however I don't understand the utility of the rest of your code ? is it to make sure that I will not be categorize as a bot ?

Comment: No, you will still be categorised as a bot.

Comment: The rest of the code is simply to handle the pop-up "accept" window that you get when you first enter that site on a fresh Chrome browser.  I am surprised you didn't encounter this before.  If you don't have any use for it then you can disregard it but I couldn't get to that site through Selenium without it.   As @vitaliis mentioned though, it has nothing to do with categorizing you as a bot or not.